# Error Sudo Docker Compose Yaml Error - Top-level object must be a mapping

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, sudo

I tried the command `sudo docker compose run web django-admin startproject moneymattersweekly`, and received the following:

`parsing /Users/eleahburman/Desktop/code/money-matters-weekly/docker-compose.yaml: Top-level object must be a mapping`

Here is my yaml file

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

and here is my Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

What is wrong with this?

I tried adding version: "3" and version: '3' to my yaml and it did nothing.  I also tried redownloading docker.